# Scientific name for living toys

Tags: vocabulary, phonetics

In a world were living toys exist and are known (like *Toy Story* but with their sentience been common knowledge), what would be the Latin scientific name for a toy? In a similar way of how *homo sapiens* means 'human that thinks'. I guess it should have the "*sapiens*" part but what would be the correct word in Latin for toy, because with Google Translate I'm seeing many options (*crepundia*, *ludibrium*, *pupa*) and not sure which one really represents the meaning of toy.

Answer (score 5):

*[crepundia](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=crepundia&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* refers to a child's rattle

*[ludibrium](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=ludibrium&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* means mockery or wantonness

*[pupa](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=pupa&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* can mean a little girl, but also a doll or a puppet - the male equivalent is *[pupus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=pupus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)*

there are also the diminutive versions *[pupula](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=pupula&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* and *[pupulus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=pupulus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* with similar meaning, except that *pupula* can also mean the pupil of an eye

I think that 'doll' would be a good description of some of the toys in Toy Story, though you might not want the confusion with 'boy', 'girl' and 'pupil'

Comment: And there's no word in latin for let say every object considered a toy? Like a generic term that encompases dolls, toy cars, teddy bears etc?

Comment: The romans didn't have a word for "yes" so it's possible their language just doesn't work that way.

Comment: But isn't true that modern latin is constantly updated with words because the Vatican uses it?

Answer (score 5):

In the name *homo sapiens*, *homo* is the genus and *sapiens* the species. So using *sapiens* for a toy would imply that there are other species of toys that would not be intelligent, but would still have a binomial name.

So the answer depends on the rest of the universe,

- if there are living toys that are not intelligent, using *pupus  sapiens* is fine,
- or else, sapiens would probably be a part of the genus, for example *sapipupus* (sapiens + pupus, compound nouns are common for this kind of use) and the second part would be different for each type of toy.

Comment: Well, all toys in the setting are sentient. Of course they might consider each different kind of toy (dolls, cars, stuffed animals) different species of the same genus but that's a level of detail that I doubt I or the reader would want to know. The problem with ''pupus'' is that it sound to similar to a bad word in the language this book will be. Is there any alternative?

Comment: While *pupus sapiens* also seems fine to me, *sapipupus* would look monstrous even in a gag.

Answer (score 1):

An inanimate object that walks and talks like a human is the Graeco-Latin "automaton".

Comment: That could work